# Using relativization to prove relative consistency

Tags: logic, set-theory

Suppose I want to prove that, for some sentence $\phi$, $Con(ZFC) \to Con(ZFC + \phi)$. And to do this, I prove that for some classe $C = \{ x : \psi(x)\}$, $C \vDash ZFC$ and $C \vDash \phi$ - using the concept of relativization of formulas. Is this enough to prove the desired result?

I thought it would go along those lines: Supose $(\mathbf{M}, E)$ is a model for ZFC and consider the set $\mathbf{N} = \{ a \in \mathbf{M} : M \vDash \psi(a) \} \subseteq \mathbf{M} $. Does the relativization argument prove that $(\mathbf{N}, E)$ is a model of $ZFC + \phi$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.  Note that strictly speaking, you can't prove (or even state) something like $C \vDash ZFC$, since $ZFC$ has infinitely many axioms and you can only relativize one of them at a time.  What you can prove is a metatheorem which says that for each individual axiom $\psi$ of $ZFC$, $C\vDash\psi$ is a theorem of $ZFC$.  This is then enough to conclude that $(\mathbf{N},E)\vDash ZFC$, by interpreting each of these theorems $C\vDash\psi$ in the model $(\mathbf{M},E)$.

Comment: +1. To the OP, to get a sense of what the second-to-last sentence here means, look at [Montague's reflection principle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18787/montagues-reflection-principle-and-compactness-theorem) if you're not familiar with it already; this is an example of a metatheorem which lets us say something about the infinitely-many axioms of ZFC, "from the outside" so to speak.

Answer (score 3):

Yup, this is correct - that would do the job. *(EDIT: although there is a serious issue here, as pointed out by Eric Wofsey's answer; this is often swept under the rug because its treatment is fairly standard, but it's important to observe at first.)*

It's worth noting however that this isn't the only way to prove consistency, though. In particular, by far the most important technique in set theory for establishing consistency results, [**forcing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics)), does the opposite: given a countable$^1$ model $M$ of ZFC (which exists if ZFC is consistent, by the [downward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem)), forcing gives us a way to try to produce models of ZFC + [desired principle] which are *bigger than* $M$, rather than looking for a substructure inside $M$.

---

$^1$OK, a bit of clarification is necessary since otherwise you might very reasonably be confused if you look at the literature on forcing:

- In most presentations you'll see the hypothesis that a countable *well-founded* (or *transitive*) model of ZFC exists, which is strictly stronger than the mere consistency of ZFC. However, this is unnecessary: forcing can be developed over arbitrary countable models of ZFC without difficulty.
- A variant of forcing can be developed even over uncountable models of ZFC, where instead of building a literally larger model we produce a more general object - a ["Boolean-valued model"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean-valued_model#Boolean-valued_models_and_syntactic_forcing) - which is still enough for consistency results. This approach actually has a lot of virtues, but it's definitely more technically involved, and one should understand the usual approach to forcing first.
- Obnoxiously, actual *research* in set theory tends to be glib about the actual behavior of forcing. Most egregiously, we often talk about the existence of a forcing extension of $V$, the "true universe of all sets," which is clearly nonsense! What's going on here is that  we're really using a shorthand for either the Boolean-valued-model or the countable-model approach to forcing, since these are sufficiently well-understood that the translation between them (and the translation of the abuse of language used) is left to the reader. But this is *absolutely* a huge stumbling block to anyone learning this for the first time. That said, it's also totally addictive: it makes it so much easier to think up forcing arguments, even if the reasoning it produces looks a priori like gibberish!